# Database Theory: Transaction serializability

Tags: database, theory, equivalence

Hy,
I'm learning for my exams and came over the following question:

Take the [History](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Schedule_(computer_science)) (or Schedule)

```
H = w1[x] w2[x] w2[y] c2 w1[y] w3[x] w3[y] c3 w1[z] c1
```

where `w1[x]` means: Transaction 1 writes to Data-Object X (`r1[x]` means read) and `c1` means: Transaction 1 commits.

Why is this transaction [view serializable](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Serializability#View_and_conflict_serializability)?

For view Serializability the History H must be view-equivalent to a sequential executing of the transaction 1,2,3. So, futher, the last-writes of each data-Object must be the same as in a sequential execution of the transaction of the History H. So the last-Writes of H are:

- Transation 3 for x and y and
- Transation 1 for z

But, in no sequential execution the last-writes are distributed like this, so the History H can't be view serializable.

Where is my mistake?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, found out myself: The last sentence if of course wrong:

In fact the sequential execution 1,2,3 leads to this History:

```
w1[x] w1[y] w1[z] c1   w2[x] w2[y] c2    w3[x] w3[y] c3
```

and the follogint last-Writes:

- Transaction 3 for x and y and
- Transaction 1 for z

which is the same than the last-writes of History H